# Why i couldn't kill the NOHUP process?

Tags: process, kill, nohup

So in order to keep my simple blog running permanently, i used the `nohup` command:

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Everything worked perfectly, my blog keep running even though i logged out of Terminal.
But now I don't want to run it anymore, so I tried to kill it but I got an error:

```
# ps aux | grep nohup
root     23427  0.0  0.0 103308   860 pts/1    S+   11:56   0:00 grep nohup
# kill -9 23427
bash: kill: (23427) - No such process
```

And of course, my blog still keeps running, so I don't understand what just happened. Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You didn't have a `nohup` process.  Your search found an instance of `grep` which was searching for `nohup`, but by the time you got your next prompt, the `grep` process had already terminated.  You're actually looking for a `python` instance.

```
ps aux | grep python | grep manage.py # This will show you the process you're looking for
kill $(ps aux | grep python | grep manage.py | awk '{print $2}') # This will kill it.
```

Comment: The grep process had already terminated? Could you tell me what would be the reason and what should i do next, please?

Comment: Your command, `ps aux | grep nohup` was searching the process list for any instance of any process (including paramaters) matching `nohup`.  While it was running, it found itself, because `grep nohup` contains the string `nohup`.  The `grep` then finished, so when you tried to `kill` the `grep` process you found, which had already self-terminated, you were rightly told there was no such process.

Comment: It worked! I was able to kill that process! Thanks!

Comment: Pleased to have been of service.

Comment: or just `kill $(ps aux | awk '/ [m]anage.py/ {print $2}')`.  Better yet, run `manage.py` inside `screen` or `tmux` or similar rather than with `nohup`. Then you easily can re-attach to the `screen`/`tmux`/whatever session later if/when you need to.  You can attach/detach/re-attach as many times as you like.

Comment: `screen` is a solution to _so_ many problems.